# Get attachment ID by file path in WordPress

Tags: wordpress

I know the path of the file and I like to get the attachment ID.

There's a function [`wp_get_attachment_url()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_get_attachment_url) which requires the ID to get the URL but I need it reverse (with path not URL though)

Comment: url and path are NOT the same.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

I used this cool snipped by pippinsplugins.com

Add this function in your functions.php file

```
// retrieves the attachment ID from the file URL
function pippin_get_image_id($image_url) {
    global $wpdb;
    $attachment = $wpdb->get_col($wpdb->prepare("SELECT ID FROM $wpdb->posts WHERE guid='%s';", $image_url )); 
        return $attachment[0]; 
}
```

Then use this code in your page or template to store / print / use the ID:

```
// set the image url
$image_url = 'http://yoursite.com/wp-content/uploads/2011/02/14/image_name.jpg';

// store the image ID in a var
$image_id = pippin_get_image_id($image_url);

// print the id
echo $image_id;
```

Original post here: https://pippinsplugins.com/retrieve-attachment-id-from-image-url/

Hope ti helps ;)
Francesco

Comment: It's the path not the url I have but your solution works (with a little tweak) Thanks!

Comment: Look below further down this post... don't use this function, use the now official WP functionality in attachment_url_to_postid()

Comment: Unfortunately, you can't guarantee that the guid is always the same as the image URL. A guid is constant and set at creation; if the image location ever changes, then this cade will no longer work.

Comment: @AdamJones glad I saw your comment—almost implemented this instead of using the native function you referenced.

Comment: You can never rely on guid. It should be used only as an internal id.

Answer (score 48):

UPDATE: since wp 4.0.0 there's a new function that could do the job. I didn't tested it yet, but it's this:

https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/attachment_url_to_postid/

---

OLD ANSWER: so far, the best solution I've found out there, is the following:

https://frankiejarrett.com/2013/05/get-an-attachment-id-by-url-in-wordpress/

I think It's the best for 2 reasons:

- It does some integrity checks
- [important!] it's domain-agnostic. This makes for safe site moving. To me, this is a key feature.

Comment: This should be the accepted answer. The approach used in the WordPress function is much more robust than relying on the guid. Read the comments on Pippins page to understand the limitations.

Comment: Link only answers are discouraged.  Copy the relevant bits of code to your answer, please.  Also, the question asks about the file _path_, not the file URL - the function you've cited does not work with _paths_.

Comment: I actually found Frankie Jarrett the only one that would work for my case. Thanks.

Comment: Honestly this should be marked as the correct answer. I have no doubt the function written by @FrancescoCarlucci works 99% of the time, but when there's an official function available in WP that does _exactly_ what the OP asks for then why not?

Comment: This is the wrong answer to the question, since the question asks how to get ID by PATH. Path is NOT url

Answer (score 9):

Try `attachment_url_to_postid` function.

```
$rm_image_id = attachment_url_to_postid( 'http://example.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/05/castle-old.jpg' );
echo $rm_image_id;
```

[More details](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/attachment_url_to_postid/)

Comment: The question is for _path_, not _url_.  This does not work for the path.

Answer (score 6):

None of the other answers here appear to work properly or reliably for a file *path*.  The answer using Pippin's function also is flawed, and doesn't really do things "the WordPress Way".

This function will support either a path OR a url, and relies on the built-in WordPress function attachment_url_to_postid to do the final processing properly:

```
/**
 * Find the post ID for a file PATH or URL
 *
 * @param string $path
 *
 * @return int
 */
function find_post_id_from_path( $path ) {
    // detect if is a media resize, and strip resize portion of file name
    if ( preg_match( '/(-\d{1,4}x\d{1,4})\.(jpg|jpeg|png|gif)$/i', $path, $matches ) ) {
        $path = str_ireplace( $matches[1], '', $path );
    }

    // process and include the year / month folders so WP function below finds properly
    if ( preg_match( '/uploads\/(\d{1,4}\/)?(\d{1,2}\/)?(.+)$/i', $path, $matches ) ) {
        unset( $matches[0] );
        $path = implode( '', $matches );
    }

    // at this point, $path contains the year/month/file name (without resize info)

    // call WP native function to find post ID properly
    return attachment_url_to_postid( $path );
}
```

Comment: You are genius! Thank you!

Comment: This was precisely what I needed. None of the other solutions takes into account the resizing that WP does. Imo, this should be the accepted answer.

Answer (score 4):

### Cropped URLs

None of the previous answers supported ID lookup on attachment URLs that contain a crop.

e.g: `/uploads/2018/02/my-image-300x250.jpg` v.s. `/uploads/2018/02/my-image.jpg`

### Solution

Micah at WP Scholar wrote a [blog post](https://wpscholar.com/blog/get-attachment-id-from-wp-image-url/) and uploaded the code to this [Gist](https://gist.github.com/wpscholar/3b00af01863c9dc562e5).  It handles both original and cropped URL lookup.

I included the code below as a reference but, if you find useful, I'd encourage you to leave a comment on his post or ***star*** the gist.

```
/**
 * Get an attachment ID given a URL.
 * 
 * @param string $url
 *
 * @return int Attachment ID on success, 0 on failure
 */
function get_attachment_id( $url ) {

    $attachment_id = 0;

    $dir = wp_upload_dir();

    if ( false !== strpos( $url, $dir['baseurl'] . '/' ) ) { // Is URL in uploads directory?

        $file = basename( $url );

        $query_args = array(
            'post_type'   => 'attachment',
            'post_status' => 'inherit',
            'fields'      => 'ids',
            'meta_query'  => array(
                array(
                    'value'   => $file,
                    'compare' => 'LIKE',
                    'key'     => '_wp_attachment_metadata',
                ),
            )
        );

        $query = new WP_Query( $query_args );

        if ( $query->have_posts() ) {

            foreach ( $query->posts as $post_id ) {

                $meta = wp_get_attachment_metadata( $post_id );

                $original_file       = basename( $meta['file'] );
                $cropped_image_files = wp_list_pluck( $meta['sizes'], 'file' );

                if ( $original_file === $file || in_array( $file, $cropped_image_files ) ) {
                    $attachment_id = $post_id;
                    break;
                }

            }

        }

    }

    return $attachment_id;
}
```

Another pro with this solution is that we leverage the `WP_Query` class instead of making a direct SQL query to DB.

Comment: Yes! Well done, needed a solution for the cropped urls, works splendidly.

Answer (score 0):

### Find IDs for resized images, PDFs and more

Like [GFargo pointed out](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50335619/4481226), most of the answers assume the attachment is an image.  Also [attachment_url_to_postid](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/attachment_url_to_postid/) assumes a url (not a file path).

I believe this better answers the actual question when supplied a file (with path):

```
function getAttachmentIDFromFile($filepath)
{
    $file = basename($filepath);
    $query_args = array(
        'post_status' => 'any',
        'post_type'   => 'attachment',
        'fields'      => 'ids',
        'meta_query'  => array(
            array(
                'value'   => $file,
                'compare' => 'LIKE',
            ),
        )
    );

    $query = new WP_Query($query_args);

    if ($query->have_posts()) {
        return $query->posts[0]; //assume the first is correct; or process further if you need
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Based on the answer from @FrancescoCarlucci I could do some improvements.

Sometimes, for example when you edit an image in WordPress, it creates a copy from the original and adds the copys upload path as post meta (key `_wp_attached_file`) which is not respected by the answer.

Here the refined query that includes these edits:

```
function jfw_get_image_id($file_url) {
    $file_path = ltrim(str_replace(wp_upload_dir()['baseurl'], '', $file_url), '/');

    global $wpdb;
    $statement = $wpdb->prepare("SELECT `ID` FROM `wp_posts` AS posts JOIN `wp_postmeta` AS meta on meta.`post_id`=posts.`ID` WHERE posts.`guid`='%s' OR (meta.`meta_key`='_wp_attached_file' AND meta.`meta_value` LIKE '%%%s');",
        $file_url,
        $file_path);

    $attachment = $wpdb->get_col($statement);

    if (count($attachment) < 1) {
        return false;
    }

    return $attachment[0]; 
}
```