# How to get thumbnail instead of the first image?

Tags: php, wordpress

I have a following piece of code:

```
    function get_first_image_url($html) {
    if (preg_match('/<img.+?src="(.+?)"/', $html, $matches)) {
        return $matches[1];
    }
}
```

How can I change it to be able to get the thumbnail instead of first image?

Answer (score 0):

It depends entirely on how your theme is set up. Some may be placing the thumbnail as a background image source, in an entirely new div, etc., and it may vary on each and every page template.

Luckily WordPress has a slew of functions to help you grab the thumbnail programatically without parsing the HTML, such as [`get_the_post_thumbnail()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_the_post_thumbnail/), [`get_the_post_thumbnail_url()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_the_post_thumbnail_url/), [`wp_get_attachment_image()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_get_attachment_image/), and multiple others that allow you get the the thumbnail based on the post ID, image ID, or whatever fields you have access to at that point.

There's also some non-native functions people have come up with that will fetch the attachment ID based on the URL (like a reverse[`wp_get_attachment_image()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_get_attachment_url/)) which would allow you to grab the "thumbnail size" based on the URL if that's what you need: [Get attachment ID by file path in WordPress](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25671108/get-attachment-id-by-file-path-in-wordpress)