# Set an already uploaded image as featured image of a post in WordPress

Tags: wordpress

I want to set featured images for different posts on WordPress website if the images are already uploaded on the server.

I plan on using the following code to do so:

```
// File has already been uploaded
$image_url = 'path/of/image';
if(file_exists($image_url)) {
    set_post_thumbnail($post_id, $image_id);
}
```

The problem is that I cannot figure out how to get the `$image_id` from just the image URL and nothing else. Is it possible in WordPress?

I would just like to clarify again that the image is already in the media library.

I have read this question: https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/40301/how-do-i-set-a-featured-image-thumbnail-by-image-url-when-using-wp-insert-post but it does not tell me how to get the `id` of an image that is already in the media library.

I need something that is opposite of `wp_get_attachment_url($id)`. This function returns the image path based on its id.

I want to get the image id based on its path or URL.

Thanks.

Comment: I understand you have uploaded a picture and you know the path , and now you want to create a thumbnail of that picture ?

Comment: @HenryStack, No. :). I want to set that image as a featured image for a WordPress post.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please Use the below code :

```
$image_url = 'path/of/image';
if(file_exists($image_url)) {

    global $wpdb;
    $table_name = $wpdb->prefix . "posts";
    $attachment = $wpdb->get_col($wpdb->prepare("SELECT ID FROM $table_name WHERE guid='%s';", $image_url ));
    $image_id = $attachment[0]; 
    set_post_thumbnail($post_id, $image_id);

}
```

I hope it will help you.

Comment: Thanks dinseshkashera :)

Could you please explain how it works so that I can do something like this myself in future?

What is `guid`? Here is a comment from an answer on a similar question: Unfortunately, you can't guarantee that the guid is always the same as the image URL. A guid is constant and set at creation; if the image location ever changes, then this cade will no longer work. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25671108/get-attachment-id-by-file-path-in-wordpress/31743463

Comment: guid will be always same as it will be available in posts table. In which WP store image link . If your image will be save on other location then you need to query according to them. But In Wordpress i suggest answer.

Comment: Thanks dinsesh :). So, this means that as long as my image is uploaded in the default WordPress folder, I don't have to worry about it?

Comment: @RealNoob yes, you no need to worry if you are using default method of wordpress for storing attachments. please do uparrow so it helps other developer too. :)

Answer (score 0):

Try the following.

- Go to **Media** menu in admin dashboard and click **library** submenu
- Click on the uploaded image so that you can view the image maximized
- In the URL you can see `post.php?post=1234&action=edit`

See the value `post=1234`part of url, `1234` is the image id. Please try with this and let me know if it works.